# Reinstalling Ubuntu alongside Windows (Bootmanager)

Tags: dual-boot

I'm currently working on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS but I encountered some problems with the compatibility to older software e.g. even with a lot of searching I wasn't able to resolve the errors for the following command
`sudo apt-get install swig ipython python-dev python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib --install-recommends`
which gives me the following errors

```
E: Package 'ipython' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'python-scipy' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'python-matplotlib' has no installation candidate
```

Therefore, I'd like to downgrade to 18.04 LTS. I think there is no other way than reinstalling 18.04 LTS on my system. My question is now, what is the best way to do this when I still want my Windows up and running. I'm asking because the last time when I installed Linux alongside Windows, I followed the recommendations of a website and my whole system was not bootable anymore. It took me a whole day to get it up and running again. My biggest question is, how to organize the bootmanager. It looks like shown in the picture now. [image] If i read the output of the Grub Customizer correctly, there are two bootmanagers installed at the moment. One on /dev/sdb2 and the other one on / (root)? At startup, Windows starts automatically. If I want to start with Ubuntu, I have to hit the F11 key and choose the 'ubuntu' entry in the start menu. This is a behavior I can absolutely live with.

Comment: Have you ever heard of a Python virtual environment?

Comment: No, I haven't but I'll google it. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Just by quick googling: You seem to have age-old instructions. On 20.04, everything is switched to python 3, with the name now `python3-mathplotlib`. Same for scipy and ipython. Just add a 3 after the python part.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%22Python+virtual+environment%22+score%3A1

Comment: `sudo apt install swig ipython3 python3-dev python3-numpy python3-scipy python3-matplotlib --install-recommends` would definitely work on 20.04. If you don't have pressing reasons to stay with unsupported python, you should use this and stay on 20.04.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I did this already (added a 3 everywhere). Nevertheless, the package I want to install doesn't compile properly. They provide the information, that everything was tested successfully on Python 2.7 (and they also note, that there might be troubles with Python 3)

Comment: Which package do you want to install? Without good information, we cannot give good answers.

Comment: I think I solved the Python problem. But now one with Fortran popped up. When I want to run the mexa64 file from https://www.pardiso-project.org/ in my Matlab I get an error that  libgfortran.so.3 can't find the file. Sadly, I can't install gfortran3 on 20.04 anymore